# Is it more performant to access function from variable?

Tags: python

I was reading [sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/statistics.py#L189) of Python `statistics` module and saw strage variable `partials_get = partials.get` which then was used once in for loop `partials[d] = partials_get(d, 0) + n`.

```py
def _sum(data, start=0):
    count = 0
    n, d = _exact_ratio(start)
    partials = {d: n}
    partials_get = partials.get  # STRANGE VARIABLE
    T = _coerce(int, type(start))
    for typ, values in groupby(data, type):
        T = _coerce(T, typ)  # or raise TypeError
        for n, d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
            count += 1
            partials[d] = partials_get(d, 0) + n  # AND IT'S USAGE
    if None in partials:
        # The sum will be a NAN or INF. We can ignore all the finite
        # partials, and just look at this special one.
        total = partials[None]
        assert not _isfinite(total)
    else:
        # Sum all the partial sums using builtin sum.
        # FIXME is this faster if we sum them in order of the denominator?
        total = sum(Fraction(n, d) for d, n in sorted(partials.items()))
    return (T, total, count)
```

So my question: Why not just write `partials[d] = partials.get(d, 0) + n`? Is it slower than storing  and calling function from variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`partials.get` has to search for the `get` attribute, starting with the object's dictionary and then going to the dictionary of the class and its parent classes. This will be done each time through the loop.

Assigning it to a variable does this lookup once, rather than repeating it.

This is a microoptimization that's typically only significant if the loop has many repetitions. The `statistics` library often processes large data sets, so it's reasonable here. It's rarely needed in ordinary application code.

Comment: `sum()` is implemented in C, isn't it? OP's asking about `statistics._sum`, if you were confused.

Comment: That makes sense, although the reasoning is still the same. `statistics` expects to process large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **yes**.

Python is an interpreted language, and while dictionary/attribute access is blazingly fast and very optimized, it still incurs a hit.

Since they are running this in a tight loop, they are taking the slight performance advantage of removing the "dot" from accessing `partials.get`.

There are other slight improvements from doing this in other cases where the variable is enough of a hint to the compiler (for cpython at least) to ensure this stays local, but I'm not sure this is the case here.